# To T or not to T in "Oft"

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters

I don't pronounce the "T" in "often", and while I realize this is primarily a matter of preference in modern days, there is some historical precedent and plenty out there on internet to justify the silent "T".

I treat "oft" in the same manner. Recently I was searching for something, *anything* online to back me up on this but came up empty handed, save a handful of really appalling "how-to-pronounce" videos on youtube.

Should the "T" in "oft" be silent?

Comment: Do you use a silent "t" in *soft* because the "t" in *soften* is silent?

Comment: no - I would definitely pronounce the "t" in soft. but I've probably omitted it in "software".  now I'm not sure..  I could be influenced by the silent "t" in the common compound word "ofttimes" - but now I'm unsure if that one's just omitted because of the double-t.

Comment: What do dictionaries (which monitor usage) say?

Comment: ***ofttimes / oftimes*** (with or without both /t/'s) is uncommon compared to ***oftentimes***, as [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ofttimes%2Coftimes%2Coftentimes&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows. Note that the ***full*** (paywalled) OED says of the latter: *Now chiefly North American; otherwise **archaic or literary.*** It's also worth pointing out that the first two pronunciations given in the OED for the US usage are **/ˈɔf(ə)nˌtaɪmz/** and **/ˈɑf(ə)nˌtaɪmz/.** The two "double-t" versions (presumably, *less common*) come later.

Comment: The "t" in "software" and "erstwhile" is pronounced, but very quickly because it's part of a consonant cluster where it's difficult to enunciate each consonant. There's no similar problem in "oft", although it might depend on what the next word is.

Comment: @Barmar: Not so. I'm virtually incapable of pronouncing the /t/ in "software" (nor did I ever pronounce it in "Softworks", under which name I traded for many years). I don't say "erstwhile" very "offen", obviously, but I would normally make at least *some* attempt to articulate the /t/ there.

Comment: Does anyone say *oft* unless (1) when reading poetry, in which case you'll enunciate far more clearly than normally or (2) as an affectation, in which case, ditto? Is it dialect somewhere?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just said "software" several times, and I'm pretty sure I hear a very quick /t/, kind of like in "between".

Comment: The OP should report what was found in some dictionaries, and include that in the question.  My dictionary says *oft* is "archaic, poetic, or jocular".

Comment: I rarely hear oft by itself, but as part of a construction like "oft-quoted" it's less rare.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is actually an interesting question about alveolar plosive elision. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a retired IBM software engineer I always pronounced the t (albeit briefly as Barma says) as did all my colleagues and anything you ever heard from management or at conferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As most dictionaries will tell you, the word on its own does end with a /t/. However, that /t/ is likely not to be pronounced when followed by a word starting with a consonant. This is due to a phenomenon called **alveolar plosive elision.** As [this book chapter explains,](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/8134091/mod_resource/content/1/Carley%2C%20Mees%20%20Collins%20%282018%29%20-%20Chapter%2012-%20Connected%20Speech.pdf) /t/ is often elided when it occurs between two consonants and the preceding consonant is in the same syllable as the /t/. So many speakers won't pronounce the /t/s in *lifts,* *software,* and *lift me.*

Since *oft* typically occurs in phrases like *oft-repeated,* where it is followed by a consonant, the /t/ in *oft* will oft go unpronounced. I suspect that this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Very interesting stuff. As is often the case, I suspect there are cultural and regional factors at play and it makes me wonder how much this phenomenon influences convention.